# SQLite insert into table using the id from an inner insert

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to insert a parent and child at the same time.

My idea is to insert the parent, get the id using `SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS [Id]` and use this id to insert the child

I can get each part of this working independently but not as a whole. This is what I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO ParentTable (Col1) 
VALUES( 'test') 
SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS [Id]
```

The above works - so far so good. Now I want to use the result of this in the child insert. This is what I have:

```
INSERT INTO ChildTable (col1, col2, ParentId) 
VALUES( 1, 2, SELECT Id FROM (
    INSERT INTO ParentTable (Col1) 
    VALUES( 'test') 
    SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS [Id] 
);
```

I get this error:

> near "SELECT": syntax error:

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: From what language are you using SQLite?

Comment: I'm using C# thanks.

Comment: Which of the many C# SQLite database drivers are you using?

Comment: SQLite.Net v3.1

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/?

Comment: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `INSERT` in `SELECT` statement. You should first insert and then use last inserted id:

```
INSERT INTO ParentTable (Col1) VALUES( 'test');

INSERT INTO ChildTable (col1, col2, ParentId) 
    VALUES(1,2, (SELECT last_insert_rowid()));
```

Since you want to insert many records with parent ID, here is a workaround:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp(id integer);
DELETE FROM temp;
INSERT INTO ParentTable (Col1) VALUES( 'test');
INSERT INTO temp SELECT last_insert_rowid();
INSERT INTO ChildTable (col1, col2, ParentId) 
    VALUES(1,2, (SELECT id FROM temp LIMIT 1));
.............
COMMIT;
DROP TABLE temp;
```

Or you can create a permanent table to this effect.

Comment: I've just been testing using this method - the problem is I have hundreds of children to insert - using the `last_insert_rowid` again results in the id being for the previous child - I need some kind of variable to store the parent id in for use in the child inserts. I don't think SQLite has variables? Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

That [SQLite.Net PCL driver](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) assumes that you use the ORM: inserting an object will automatically read back and assign the autoincremented ID value.

If you're using raw SQL, you have to manage the [`last_insert_rowid()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) calls yourself.
Your idea is correct, but you have to do everything in separate SQL statements:

```
BEGIN;                       -- better use RunInTransaction()

INSERT INTO Parent ...;
SELECT last_insert_rowid();  --> store in a variable in your program

INSERT INTO Child ...;
...

END;
```

(SQLite is an embedded database and has no client/server communication overhead; there is no reason to try to squeeze everything into a single statement.)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to run more than one sql statement at a time - if I create a long string with SQL statements then only the first one seems to be run

Comment: Separate statements means separate strings.