# SQLite INSERT INTO using SELECT and last_insert_rowid

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm working on an SQLite based project to save tagged items.
I create thee tables: item, tag and item_tag like so :

```
CREATE TABLE 'item'(id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT primary key, ...);
CREATE TABLE 'tag'(name TEXT primary key); // <- actually, don't care about performance here
CREATE TABLE 'item_tag'(item_id..., tag_id..., PRIMARY KEY(item_id, tag_id));
```

'tag' table is prefilled and now I wan't to create a batch file to insert a lot of items.

I use this SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO item VALUES(NULL, ...);
INSERT INTO item_tag SELECT last_insert_rowid() AS item_id, tag.name AS tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag.name IN('tag1','tag3');
```

The `SELECT` query from the second INSERT works fine alone. But within the `INSERT`, except for the first inserted `item_tag`, `last_insert_rowid` refers to the last `item_tag` rowid, not from `item`.

If it is the attended behaviour for a such query, is there a different way to do what I want?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What language are you using to access SQLite?

Comment: I use sqlite CLI within a bash terminal. But I'd appreciate to use such queries from any SQLite API, like Android or so.

Comment: For bash, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44353198/11654), but you should really use a real programming language where a variable is easier.

Comment: Thanks @CL. for the link. I was actually thinking about a such solution but that's a bit verbose for hundreds of values... We may have the same problematic with the Android API allowing batch queries and that the reason I was looking for a one-query solution.
Seems not possible though..